# Recursive Feature Elimination with Support Vector Machine using Kernel Poly

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, rfe

I would like to run recurve feature elimination with support vetor machine using kernel = poly.
I used the code from the manual (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html), while modifying the kernel = poly.

However, it does not work. Does anybody happen to know why it gives an error message?

Ran the code with `kernel = poly`.

Comment: What error message? See [mre]